# PHP header redirect function not working

Tags: php, mysql, whatsapp

Hie i need a littles help i have php code like below, when i try to use the header redirect php function it wont work as you can see below. The problem is with the last two lines of code

```
    <?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../src/whatsprot.class.php';
$username = '11111111';                     
$password = '9lW8oEhIwuKtVPKouTffefee=';    
$nickname = 'NUMBER';                          
$debug = true;                                           
$w = new WhatsProt($username, $nickname, $debug);
$w->connect();
$w->loginWithPassword($password);
?>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT number FROM testnumbers";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
// Associative array
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))

{
     $storeArray[] =  $row['number'];   
    };
    $arrlength = count($storeArray);
    for($x = 0; $x <= $arrlength; $x++) {
//send picture
$w->sendMessageImage($storeArray[$x], 'demo/filepage1.jpg');

$w->pollMessage();
}
    header('location: index.php'); //not working
exit(); //not working
```

Comment: header is case sensitive, you need to utilize Location in place of location. capital L

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: There is some echo changing the header so the redirect won't work, You have to remove the echo, you can also redirect the output see: [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Comment: Its not case sensitive but better to use capital letter . Must remove the white spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change `location` to `Location`, but secondly make sure you remove ANY output that happens before the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function. This includes:

1. All `echo` statements.
2. Any whitespace outside of the PHP tags (spaces and tabs).
3. Make sure you check in all included/required files and in the constructor of the `WhatsProt` class you have created an instance of.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. In your script, The first letter"L" in Location keyword is not capital.

```
    header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: Is there any sort of error message? like "Header already sent"